# add recipients to "Customer invoice / Order details" in Woocommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, there is already a built-in way to add recipients to the "New Order" , "Failed", and "Cancelled" emails, but for some reason, the "Customer invoice / Order details" don't allow any recipient other than the customer.

There is a simple plugin that allows for that, but it is very limited in features.

Any guidance for how to add recipients to this email?

I plan to use a Code Snippet to call the hook/filter/action and then tell it explicitly which email addresses to use.  I intend to write the script so that whatever user initiates the action, will be CC'ed on that email.  Presumably the same function that can do the first part of my question can help me to check current user and will grab their email address.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what buil-in functionality are you talking about. But you can use the below filter to add recipients to the invoice email. You don't need any plugin, just use this below code snippet in your active theme/child theme functions.php

```
add_filter("woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_invoice", "add_recipient_to_email", 10, 2);
function add_recipient_to_email( $recipients, $object ){
    $new_email = "newemail@domain.com"; //New email Id
    $recipients = $recipients.','.$new_email;
    return $recipients;
}
```